# Можно ли задать тень для блока для каждой стороны в отдельности?

Tags: css3, css

Как задать тень для блока для каждой стороны в отдельности

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно

http://jsfiddle.net/PRz4d/

Comment: А если в одном блоке нужно добавить тень слева и снизу?

Comment: обновил ответ